# Jquery How to get data from a my json array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I have a nested data structure / JSON, how can I access a specific value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/i-have-a-nested-data-structure-json-how-can-i-access-a-specific-value)

Please I get this following json string in my ajax side :

```
    {
    "products": [
        {
            "id":            48,
            "quantity":      1,
            "priceByLine":   "950,00 €",
            "name":          "Filtre Mixte",
            "price":         "950,00 €"

        }],   

    "total": "950,00 €",
    "productTotal": "950,00 €"
   }
```

To get the **total price**, I just have to do :

```
alert(data.total);
```

But when I want to get the Id, I do :

```
alert(data.products.id);
```

It gave me **undefined** !

Please masters, how could I do to get the id ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Products is an array containing one element of type object. Hence you should type:

`alert(data.products[0].id);`

Your statement would have been valid if the structure was:

```
{
"products": 
    {
        "id":            48,
        "quantity":      1,
        "priceByLine":   "950,00 €",
        "name":          "Filtre Mixte",
        "price":         "950,00 €"

    },   

"total": "950,00 €",
"productTotal": "950,00 €"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, `data.products` is an Array, so you can't get the `id` of that Array, you need to try and lookup a property of each element within it.

For example, this would give you a result:

```
 alert(data.products[0].id);
```

But, you can try looping through that data:

```
 data.products.forEach(function(product) {
      alert(product.id);
 });
```

Note the above `forEach` won't work in bad old browsers (including IE8), but it will work in anything modern. Use a [for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) if you need to support older ones.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but if you try this :

```
alert(data.products[0].id);
```

Because products key seem to be an array, but with only one row.

Answer (score 0):

try this.. since your products is in array

```
alert(data.products[0].id);
```